# Exporting zsh history separated by ‘\0’ characters instead of ‘\n’

Tags: zsh, command-history, shell-builtin

I want to access zsh history with entries separated out by `\0` instead of `\n`. The built-in parser can clearly handle multiline entries, because `fc 123` brings up an editor with newlines preserved. However, `fc -l 123` (which prints to stdout instead of starting an editor) converts newline characters to the equivalent of `\\n`. This means that any commands in history containing the literal `\n` cannot be disambiguated from newlines (e.g., `printf "\n"` in an awk invocation).

Is there a way to get at unaltered history entries using `fc` or `history` builtins in zsh? I’m trying to avoid the effort of writing a history file parser. For reference, fish has `history -z` for this use case.

(Bonus: I want to do the same thing to analyze bash history also. Its `fc` seems to behave differently from zsh’s.)

Comment: See also [How to send output to next input line?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/706866)

Comment: AFAICT, `bash` can't store multiline history entries to `.bash_history`. They end up split into several entries.

Comment: Bash can, indeed, store multiline history entries, provided `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set. Bash used to mess up _retrieval_ of multiline entries, but that has been fixed in version 5, provided the use of `shopt -s lithist cmdhist`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1210371.

Comment: @gvc, . Looks like the `.bash_history` also need to have only entries with timestamps, i.e. you need to wipe your history before setting those options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`history`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-history-2) variable and [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) (possibly including [(associative) array index](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts)) features.

For example, the raw equivalent of `fc -l 123 123` is `$history[123]`. To get a range of history elements in an array, you can use `${(v)history[(I)<123-456>]}`. To get a null-separated list of history elements in a string, you can use `${(vpj[\0])history[(I)<123-456>]}`. (But note that history elements can contain null bytes, and you can't pass null bytes to external commands, so this isn't particularly useful.)

To *print* those NUL-delimited, you can also use `print -N`, combined with `-r` to disable backslash expansion and `-C1` so it prints nothing if there's no match:

```
print -rNC1 -- ${(v)history[(I)<123-456>]} | fzf --read0
```

Or:

```
print -rNC1 -- $history | fzf --read0
```

For the whole history for instance.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`, if we assume you don't enter commands whose second and following lines start with spaces, digits and at least 2 spaces, you could do something like:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT= history | LC_ALL=C gawk -v RS='\n *[0-9]+  ' -v ORS='\0' '
  NR==1 {sub(/^ *[0-9]+  /, "")}
  {print}'
```

To convert the history output (with timestamp removed) like:

```
  123  cmd
  124  echo 'multiline
command'
  125  ...
```

to:

```
cmd<NUL>echo 'multiline
command'<NUL>...<NUL>
```